# Getting Wrong data in Salesforce Marekting Cloud Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, unsubscriber

I have written the following query in my child BU to get data from subscribers.

```
Select
EmailAddress,Status,Subscriberkey,DateUnsubscribed
from ent._Subscribers
```

I am storing this records in Data Extension.
"Status" field for 4-records is "Unsubscribed" in Subscribers. 
but, after checking records in data extension, the Status for the Same record is Showing "active". 
all other fields data is correct
any specific reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first answer is entirely correct, BUT the solution has become much easier lately, with the introduction of the new data view businessUnitUnsubscribes, which eliminates the need for the (correct) workaround linked by Brad.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=mc_as_data_view_businessunitunsubscribes.htm&language=en_us

Hope this helps!

Edit: to clarify -

BusinessUnitUnsubscribes has the current BU-wide subscription status, IF that status is unsubscribed. It does not hold the subscriber status if it is active, held or bounced. Since it does also not hold events (unlike _Unsubscribe data view), it will always only show current status (...if it's "unsubscribed", that is.).

Comment: What about when a subscriber does an Unsub and then re opt back in? From what I can tell, BusinessUnitUnsubscribes will only capture the unsub event and not the subscribers current opt-in status. Therefore it is only telling half the story.

Comment: Hi, to my knowledge, BusinessUnitUnsubscribes has exactly the opposite: current BU-wide subscription status, not events. It was specifically added to address this problem, which was very complicated to solve (see other answer) with ENT._Subscribers and the status there.

Contrary to that, the _Unsubscribe data view indeed stores events.

Comment: This DV does not show subscriber status. It will show Spam Complaint, and RMM unsubscribes.
`SELECT SubscriberID, SubscriberKey, BusinessUnitID, UnsubDateUTC, UnsubReason FROM _BusinessUnitUnsubscribes`
[https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_businessunitunsubscribes.htm&type=5]

Comment: BUUnsubscribes does show the BU level status. I ran your query and I found one record with an UnsubReason of "test" - that user was "red" in BU level All subs due to a custom unsub link clicked in an email. (For RMM: UnsubReason holds a very specific value: "Unsubscribed by Salesforce Marketing Cloud RMM service based on subscriber Leave/Reply email." Indeed the DV is useful for finding those).

I then manually resubscribed the user on the BU level All Subscribers, and the same query returned 0 results. It does return the current status of BU-level All Subscribers.

Comment: Hi and thank you. I was able to replicate your test and confirm that if a SubKey is in this DV then that subscriber is CURRENTLY opt-out. A reactivated subscriber's 'old' unsubscribe entry is  _not_ returned once set back to active.
TESTING METHOD:
1) Add new subscriber (active)
2) Run _BusinessUnitUnsubscribes query in queryStudio (where subkey = 'xxx')
3) Result return 0 records
4) Manually unsubscribe new Contact via UI
5) Re run _BusinessUnitUnsubscribes query
6) Result return 1 record 
7) Re-activate new subscriber via UI in AllSubs
8) Re run query
9) Result return 0 record

Comment: Want to also identify that this will not reveal 'held' or 'bounced' Subscriber status, but the Mock All Subs solution from Brad will indeed show this. Depending on use case, the more sophisticated setup from Brad will make the full status range of values available for querying in the BU.

Comment: Hi, absolutely. We do agree then that BusinessUnitUnsubscribes has the current BU-wide subscription status, IF that status is unsubscribed.
It does not hold the subscriber status if it is active, held or bounced.
Since it does also not hold events (unlike _Unsubscribe), it will always only show current status (...if it's "unsubscribed").

Comment: Yep :D  Perfect summary above. Good stuff.         Perhaps you can update your answer when you have spare time to also include some of our discussion points?

Answer (score 2):

Above behaviour usually happens when you have the setting to unsubscribe subscribers from this business unit only. please refer to this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/195186/how-do-you-unsubscribe-a-subscriber-at-business-unit-level?rq=1) on this.

Moreover, when a subscriber is unsubscribed from a child BU, their Status isn't reflected into the ENT._Subscribers hence you'd see a discrepancy between your child BU and parent BU.

However, if the subscriber is unsubscribed from the parent level, the subscribers will reflect the status from parent level.

If you require to pull the right status of the subscribers in BU level, I have posted a setup in this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227390/clarifying-a-workaround-to-get-business-unit-subscriber-status/227455#227455).

More info on unsubscribe settings [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_unsubscribe_settings.htm&type=5).

Comment: this is correct , i was querying ENT._Subscribersand , i think thats why i was getting wrong status for the subscribers. if you want to query unsubscribers data in particular BU use "_BusinessUnitUnsubscribes" this DataView as mentioned by the in the another answer.. thanks.

Comment: the explanation for not able to access correct data is Perfect.